# Why does overflow-x hidden has interaction with the client bounding rect

Tags: vue.js

I have this Vue directive to detect if I scroll past a certain element. But it stopped working since I set overflow-x to hidden. So I logged all the comparisons with the client bounding rect. How can I make my scroll detection work again?

```
 import Vue from 'vue'

    Vue.directive(
      "infocus" ,  {
        bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
          let f = () => {
            let clientBoundingRect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
            console.log(clientBoundingRect.width > 0);
            console.log(clientBoundingRect.height > 0);
            console.log(clientBoundingRect.top >= 0);
            console.log(clientBoundingRect.width <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight));
            let isInView = (
              clientBoundingRect.width > 0 &&
              clientBoundingRect.height > 0 &&
              clientBoundingRect.top >= 0 &&
              clientBoundingRect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
            )
            if (isInView) {
              if(typeof binding.value === "function")
                binding.value(el);
              else
                throw new Error("v-infocus requires you to bind a method.");
              window.removeEventListener('scroll', f)
            }
          }
          window.addEventListener('scroll', f);
          f();
        }
      }
    )
```

Comment: What is the output in the console ?

Comment: they are all true

Comment: Therefore the `isInView` is also TRUE ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know why this happens when I seed overflow-x to hidden and what are ways to get around it to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Do you have a CodePen example ?